# Php Regex Tag content tag

Tags: php, regex, tags

I have one question :

I have this text in string variable :

```
$subjet = "<section>
    <article id="s1n1">
        <img src=".." alt="..">
        <p id="pa1"><p>
        <p id="pa2"><p>
        <p id="pa3"><p>
    </article>
    <article id="s1n2">
        </h2></h2>
        <p id="pa4"><p>
        <p id="pa5"><p>
        <p id="pa6"><p>
    </article>
    <article id="s1n3">
        </h2></h2>
        <p id="pa7"><p>
        <p id="pa8"><p>
        <p id="pa9"><p>
    </article>
</section>"
```

And i am trying to get the content with regex,

```
'/<article id="s1n1">(.*?)<\/article>/'
```

just the content of a first article tag, but my regex not work :/

Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you escaping those quotes within the string?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` doesn't match Newline characters by default. Add the [`s` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: `/<article id="s1n1">([\s\S]*?)<\/article>/`

Comment: @aykut Should work, too. BUt I consider it uglier than just adding the `s` - may be personal preference though.

Comment: just adding `s` instead `.` doesn't work, you must catch other chars with `\S`.

Comment: @aykut not talking about thw whitespace wildcard `\s`, but abouzt the **modifier**. See the documentation link.